# How to get a File from a URI?

Tags: android, image, file, uri

I select an image from the image gallery in my app. In the onActivityResult it returns an Intent object and I execute the getData() method on it. I get the image URI back. I am now trying to convert that in to a File so I can send it to AWS S3.
This is what I have been trying but it just returns null:

```
  String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
```

I also try

```
File file = new File(imageURI.getPath())
```

also null. Is this impossible or can somebody help?

Comment: Are u getting the image path from uri?

Comment: Yep. When I run that method I try
File file = new File(thatMethod())
and I get back: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

Comment: What path value u getpath from imageURI.getPath()

Comment: @MaxKleine: Already getting path in `filePath`

Answer (score 0):

supposing your `onActivityResult` checks in with the Intent object being `ReturnedIntent` you can do

```
File f = new File(ReturnedIntent.getData());
```

or get an inputstream and use it

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(ReturnedIntent.getData()) 
//returns inputstream
```

what is the essence of this String object `String filePath` ?